# Software to read, highlight, and annotate PDFs

Tags: pdf, ios, pdf-viewer, annotation

Is there a PDF reading app available for Mac that has the following features:

- Allows you to continue reading PDFs where you left off when opening them (automatically goes to the last page you were on). This feature is essential. Please don't recommend anything that doesn't include this.
- Lets you highlight and annotate the PDF (add comments).
- Syncs automatically between Mac, iPad, and iPhone.

A free app would be preferable.

Comment: Not sure about the first feature (that's why I make it a comment rather than an answer), but did you check Papers: http://www.papersapp.com/mac/ ?

Comment: Doesn't the built-in iBooks app cover all those features?

Comment: No mine doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

From what I could find, I think [PDF Expert](https://pdfexpert.com/) does all you need:

- you can start where you left off,
- enables you to annotate, edit, highlight, rearrange, add signatures, fill out forms, etc.
- works across devices.

However, I am not sure it is completely free. You can download the Mac version for free from the website (and you can buy licenses for 3 Macs for $49.99), to download the [iPhone/iPad version from iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-expert-6-read-annotate-edit-pdf-documents/id743974925?mt=8), you need to pay $9.99.

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 apps on my Mac. Both are free. I mainly use **Preview**. Is can edit and add annotations. If I quit the app while reading a PDF, the file is reopened when I relaunch Preview and it opens to the last page I was displaying when I quit. As far as syncing with iPad, I save the file to Dropbox or my iCloud account.

I also occasionally use Adobe Acrobat reader. It does not automatically open the file you were using, but when you open it manually it opens to the last page displayed.